# Uniqueness for each key in a composite key using EF Core and Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, fluent

The requirements :

- I have a table with a composite key [Key1, Key2]
- I need Key1 and Key2 each unique, so :

  - if [A, B] already in the table
  - [A, C] or [C, B] cannot be in the table
- I'm using EF Core 3.1.5
- I may use any database later

How to implement this constraint in EF Core?

I already did this :

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<myobject>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(a => new { a.Key1, a.Key2 });
            entity.HasIndex(a => a.Key1).IsUnique();
            entity.HasIndex(a => a.Key2 ).IsUnique();
        });
```

But this codes still works without any errors :

```
        var table = DbContext.Set<myobject>();
        table.Add(new myobject{ Key1 = "A", Key2 = "B" });
        table.Add(new myobject{ Key1 = "A", Key2 = "C" });
        table.Add(new myobject{ Key1 = "C", Key2 = "B" });
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

It seemed like they ignore the unique constraint.

Comment: curious: when both Key1 and Key2 are unique, why do you need a composite key?

Comment: To map Key1 and Key2, with Key1 or Key2 could be the primary